# Neither PackageIcon nor PackageIconUrl work in dotnet build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'm using visual studio 2017.  I have a project for which I would like to generate a nuget with an Icon.
If I use

```
...
<PackageIconUrl>http://blabla/icon.png</PackageIconUrl>
```

I get the following error :

```
error NU5048: The 'PackageIconUrl'/'iconUrl' element is deprecated. Consider using the 
'PackageIcon'/'icon' element instead. Learn more at https://aka.ms/deprecateIconUrl 
[D:\myproject.csproj]
```

Fine, So I change my project to be something like :

```
...
    <PackageIcon>core.png</PackageIcon>
...
    <Content Include="..\Shared\core.png" Link="core.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="\" >
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

When I build my project now (dotnet build Myproject.csproj) I don't get any compilation errors.
However, when I want to view the generate nupkg in "Nuget Package explorer".  I get the error :

```
The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd' 
has invalid child elment 'icon' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd'.
List of possible elements expected : 'contentFiles, desription, licenseUrl, projectUrl, language, 
releaseNotes, frameworkAssemblies, summary, iconUrl, packageTypes, dependencies, copyright, 
developmentDependency, repositoru, tags, references, title, serviceable' in namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd'.
```

(so it seems the generated embedded nuspec has a wrong xml namespace - I have no idea how I can make it generate the new namespace)  This is a Catch-22.
So it seems the only option is to leave the icon out.

(I also have visual studio 2019 and recently installed the .net core 3.0.100 SDK)

Comment: How do you view the generated nupkg? Do you upload it to nuget.org, or host it on some custom nuget package feed / local directory?

Comment: I just double-click my generated nupkg locally on my disk.

Comment: @WillyVandenDriessche Hi friend, any update for this issue? If canton7's answer helps to resolve your puzzle, you could consider marking it as answer. It just a reminder :)

Comment: Did you find a solution. I'm facing the same issue. Everything is setup like mentioned in tutorials, but still no icon.

Answer (score 5):

The move from `<iconUrl>`/`<PackageIconUrl>` to `<icon>`/`<PackageIcon>` is fairly new. While nuget.org supports parsing packages which use `<icon>` rather than `<iconUrl>`, some other package servers don't yet.

It sounds like you're simply browsing a directory with the NuGet Package Explorer, so the cause is probably that this doesn't yet understand `<icon>`.

While `<iconUrl>` is deprecated, I've found that it still works on nuget.org, so you should be able to continue using it until the rest of the tooling catches up. Alternatively if you don't *actually* care about browsing packages stored in a local directory and just care about nuget.org, then you can start using `<icon>`.

You might even be able to use both - I haven't checked.

Comment: - I browse the nupkg which is generated on my disk.
- IMHO The generated nupkg is simply wrong.  It uses the "2013" namespace while it should use <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">

Comment: If being able to do that is important to you, it's probably best to keep using `<iconUrl>` until the tooling supports `<icon>`. Don't be put off by the deprecation warning - `<iconUrl>` still works on nuget.org!

Comment: The deprecation message is not a warning but an error.  I have warnings as errors which might explain this.

Comment: Even with `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` in my csproj, `dotnet pack` still reports it as a warning.

Comment: I have now added 
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <NoWarn>NU5048</NoWarn>
    <WarningsAsErrors /> Which *seems* to solve the problem.  Like this I can use the packageUrl.

Comment: Ideally you'd use <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU5048</NoWarn> so warning suppressions passed from the CLI are also taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

At least I think you can feel free to use the `PackageIconUrl` for now, as canton7 mentioned above, the move is fairly new. You can consider that as a kind reminder.

For the latest VS2019 **release** version 16.3.3, its project template still supports `PackageIconUrl` by default. For `.net core` and `.net standard` class library project, if we `Right-click project=>Package tab` we can see:

[image]

And it is equivalent to `<PackageIconUrl>http://xxx/icon.png</PackageIconUrl>` in xx.csproj, so I think you can just ignore that warning or use `<NoWarn>NU5048</NoWarn>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the icon is part of the package. You can verify that it's in there by unzipping your nupkg file.

From a [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-an-icon-image-file):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <None Include="images\icon.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="\"/>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Also (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets)):

> PackageIconUrl is deprecated in favor of PackageIcon. However, for the best downlevel experience, you should specify PackageIconUrl in addition to PackageIcon.

There is also an example project with icon: https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/main/PackageIconExample